# Simple slide show (not my code) doesn't work

Tags: python, wxpython

This code is from python-forum and it's there to view images in a simple slideshow. It doesn't work I think because it creates the images but doesn't show them on the screen. I think i might have to implement some sort of callback but is that correct way to solve my problem? If i get rid of the while loop and just use the for it will only show one image and the not the rest.

```
class SecondFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, mysize):
        gets correct path for images from working directory
        wx.EVT_PAINT(self, self.onPaint)

    def onPaint(self, event=None):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        while self.loops > 0:
            self.loops -= 1
            for self.ix, bmp in enumerate(self.image_list):     
                w, h = bmp.GetSize()
                info = "Graphs"
                self.SetTitle(info)
                dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 10, 10, True)
                wx.MilliSleep(self.delay)
                if self.delay > 200:
                    dc.Clear()
```

Comment: We're not going to figure out why something doesn't work for you.  You need to figure out why it's not working and then query what you should do to fix that/those particular error(s)

Comment: What specific error(s) are you getting?

Comment: I know why it isn't working but I need to know what I can use to fix it. I'm not asking you to give me working code. I'm not getting any errors but it's just not showing anything. I commented out the while loop and just had the for ix, bmp...with the dc.DrawBitmap and it showed the first image.

Comment: What kevin is getting at is that your example needs to be short and self contained. Read: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure where you got that code, but as it stands it is incomplete, non-runnable and very poorly coded overall (IMHO). Try this snippet (untested):

```
class SecondFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, mysize):

        # Whatever here

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        self.SetTitle("Graphs")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnErase)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer)

        self.timer.Start(self.delay)


    def OnPaint(self, event):

        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
        dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(self.GetBackgroundColour()))
        dc.Clear()

        if self.loops <= 0:
            return

        bmp = self.image_list[self.loops]        
        w, h = bmp.GetSize()

        dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 10, 10, True)
        wx.MilliSleep(self.delay)


    def OnErase(self, event):

        pass


    def OnTimer(self, event):

        self.loops -= 1
        if self.loops <= 0:
            return

        self.Refresh()
```

The next time, please post a complete, short, runnable and standalone sample app as per wxPython guidelines:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/MakingSampleApps